# Keep parameter value when coming back from subreport

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have several multiple choice parametres that do not have default value. There is also link to other report. And parent report parametres are empty when coming back from drill through report. Is it possible to keep selected parameter values?
The parameter keeps selected values if it has default value initially. But I would like keep parametres empty on load

Comment: I am afraid, keeping parameter values is possible. Because you move to linked Report and when you come back it Reload your Main Report once again all from beginning.

Comment: @AnkUser, isn't there any workaround? I was thinking about using another hidden parameter. E.g report will have two params p1 and p2, both use same dataset. p1 is visbile and has no default values. p2 is hidden and has default values set. When p1 values changed it changes values in p2. And when coming back from subreport p1 values will be set from p2. Is it possible to realize?

Comment: You can give it a try but I think your P2 will be set to Default values as soon as you come back from Linked Report to Main Report.

Comment: @AnkUser, unfortunately I do not know how to distinguish how main report is opened, from subreport or first time. And how to copy values from parameter to second

Comment: @AnkUser -- to clarify, does your comment mean *NOT* possible or impossible?  It says "is possible" but that doesn't seem to go with what you are saying ….

Answer (score 2):

If you have an action to open a drill thru report, to get back to the parent report, you must use the 'Go back to parent report' button on the reports toolbar, NOT the browser back button.

This also means the parent report does not get re-rendered so it's instant.

[image]

This has been available since SSRS2008 as far as I know. Here's what it looked like back in 2012..

[image]

**Note: this only works if you have used the "Go to Report" action**

It won;t work if you used the go to URL option.

**Alternative approach if using Go To URL**

Basically you make sure you send all the parameters to the sub report even if they are not used. You could hide the unused ones.

Then add a button to your sub report that simply opens the parent report again and passes all the parameters back.

This is not ideal as the report will have to be rendered again, which is a pain if it's a slow report.

Another option is to open the sub report in a new tab (lots of examples on SO on doing this) so you can just close the tab.

Comment: What version of SSRS are you using? We are on 2012, and don't have that button

Comment: I'm on 2016 but this button was (as far as I remember) available back in 2008. How are you navigating to the subreport, Are you using the Go to Report action or Go to URL? It will only work if you use Go To Report

Comment: Qualified my answer a little more now and given some more options.

Comment: I'm using go to report option but I don't have that button. Go to url would be good option for me to open subreport in new tab, but url length is limited. My parameters length can exceed that limit, os I can;t use go to url option

Comment: You could same the same technique I described for got to URL but use a button and use "Go To Report" passing all your parameters back to your parent report. It is odd that that button is not there, it should be. I have seen reports of it missing before so maybe search for solutions to that issue. It's been in there since 2008 at least.

Comment: one more thought. Are you using a web viewer control or just the standard Report Manager interface? I think the web viewer control might not have this on earlier releases but the standard report manager interface does.

Comment: see this link for a possible solution to show the missing back button.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/38e96468-0951-4992-9a28-68c057213649/ssrs-drill-through-back-button-in-web-page?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Can you tell where's ShowBackButton property changed, please? I'm creating reports with report builder 3.0, and can't find that property. I also tried to open rdl file with notepad

Comment: I think the link was referring to the web viewer control so it'll either be in your custom HTML page or maybe a setting on the report server  but I don;t know where I'm afraid. I'll see if I can find something later if I get time. If not I suggest you post a new question in the relevant forum